# My Word office addin doesn't work?

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, vsto, office-interop, office-addins

I have created an office addin for Word 2010 targeting .net 4 and [this should apparently work in office 2007](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2010/06/04/creating-an-add-in-for-office-2007-and-office-2010-that-quot-lights-up-quot-on-office-2010-mclean-schofield.aspx).

I have created the installer per [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff937654.aspx) with the exception that I include a dll in the dependencies rather than in the bootstrapper for the prerequisites.

The installer installs the vsto and the registry keys in

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins\ProjectName
```

The pc also has .Net 4 and the Office 2007 Primary interop assemblies.

The addin doesn't appear in Word 2007, any ideas where I could be going wrong?

**UPDATE**:
You have to sign your addin, this was pretty obvious! Office now recognises the addin but its gets a runtime error that I can't debug. Tried [to debug with these](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsod/archive/2008/04/22/troubleshooting-com-add-in-load-failures.aspx) steps with no luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to build for correct CPU version of office, in my case 32bit, Any CPU didn't work!